# Unusable Compute Node in Batch pool

Tags: azure-batch

I am trying to create a pool with an **application package** installed on all nodes, however I keep getting that the **compute nodes are unusable**. My guess was that there was an error with the installation of application packages that caused the nodes to go to the unusable state. But then I got confused as I am able to install the same application packages at a task level in another pool. 
What could possibly be the problem? What causes the nodes to go to unusable state? And if my guess was right, What could cause an application package not to be installed properly in a pool and how can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hiya @J.B. Yep, you are correct, `:)` it has to do with the failure which has happened while installation and this has caused the handler for the failure to come into play, and caused the node to go into `unusable` state. can you share your scenario in detail and I will help you out. Node will go to failure state if there is an installation failure of app pkg. If you will see my past example in the demo I created for you, problem could be in the scenario or in the code, please let me know and I will help out and resolve it for you. feel free to share a sample to repro if you want, Thks,

Comment: :bulb: idea, You can also try to scale down your pool so that all nodes are fresh, and then try your sample. This is to make sure that the node in play is not corrupt. `:)` I tried again with a demo and left a node for a bit and not able to see this behaviour, Please let me know and we can makje sure we reolve it for you, it should be something small. Thanks.

Comment: Hiya @J.B I have identified something within service, which seemingly not related, but fix should be on its way, in the mean time please do share your scenario with me, to understand this better and I can help out `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Thanks a lot for all your comments and for the help. I am just trying out few things to see if that would fix the problem I was having. I will share my scenario after those fixes. Thanks!

Comment: @Tats_innit what did you identify within service? I have been having a different issue with application packages where sometimes/ many times (depends on the day) I just get a null exit code and BlobAccessDenied Error for the same exact application package and same exact command line that was previously working. Today, I've been getting this error for the exact same packages and commands that I ran yesterday. Is this a bug in the service?

Comment: Cool, can you please share a code snippet or a sample code so that I can diagnose it further. Thanks, I should be able to exactly pin point what is the cause. `:)`